# How to simulate or trigger a AsyncPostBackError in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asyncpostbackerror

I have implemented the handling of the AsyncPostBackError.  Now I want to test it.

How do simulate a AsyncPostBackError event?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply `throw` an exception in the serverside method that is being called async.  That should raise your handling of the `AsyncPostBackError`.